# react js issues with delete function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

So I have been trying to figure out a delete function for a contact app I am attempting to make as I learn react. So far I have a removeContact function that partially works. It will delete a contact but does not delete the correct contact, instead it always deletes the first contact. I have been stuck on this issue for the last two weeks and from what I can see I think I am not getting the function to accept the id from my contact object correctly. It's driving me crazy so any help would be appreciated. Thank you! 
Below are three of my compnents; app, contactlist and contactCard.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/Menu/NavBar';
import SideBar from './components/Menu/SideBar';
import AddForm from './components/Menu/AddForm';
import ContactList from './components/Contacts/ContactList';






class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      contacts: [
        {first:'Josh',last:'McDaniel',number:'555-666-7777',email:'joshmcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
        {first:'Briana',last:'McDaniel',number:'888-999-1111',email:'brianamcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
        {first:'Finn',last:'McDaniel',number:'222-333-4444',email:'finnmcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
        {first:'Josh',last:'McDaniel',number:'555-666-7777',email:'joshmcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
        {first:'Briana',last:'McDaniel',number:'888-999-1111',email:'brianamcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
        {first:'Finn',last:'McDaniel',number:'222-333-4444',email:'finnmcdaniel@gmail.com',area:'Mount Morris, Ny',instagram:'https://www.instagram.com/mcdanije/', facebook:'https://www.facebook.com/josh.mcdaniel.5201', linkedin:'https://www.linkedin.com/in/mcdanije/',twitter:'https://twitter.com/'},
      ],
        toggle:true,
        class: 'modalClose', 
        searchField:'',

        first: '',
        last: '',
        number: '',
        email:'',
        area:'',
        instagram: '',
        facebook: '',
        linkedin:'',
        twitter:''
            }
    }



  //functions for modal start//
addModalToggle = () => {
   this.setState({class:'modal'})
}
closeModalToggle = () =>{
  this.setState({class:'modalClose'})
}
  //functions for modal start//

  //functions that capture form data start//
firstChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({first:event.target.value})
  console.log(this.state.first)
}
lastChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({last:event.target.value})
  console.log(this.state.last)
}
numberChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({number:event.target.value})
  console.log(this.state.number)
}
emailChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({email:event.target.value})
  console.log(this.state.email)
}
locationChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({area:event.target.value})
  console.log(this.state.area)
}
instagramChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({instagram:event.target.value})
}
  //functions that capture form data end//

  //logic for adding contact object to state start//
submitData = (event) => {
    if (this.state.first==''||this.state.last==''||this.state.number==''||this.state.email==''||this.state.area==''){
      alert('Please Fill In All Fields')
      event.preventDefault();
    }else {
 let newContact = {
    first:this.state.first,
    last:this.state.last,
    number:this.state.number,
    email:this.state.email,
    area:this.state.area,
    instagram:this.state.instagram,
    facebook:this.state.facebook,
    linkedin:this.state.linkedin,
    twitter:this.state.twitter
  }


this.setState({contacts:this.state.contacts.concat([newContact])})
  document.getElementById("form").reset();
this.setState({class:'modalClose'})
this.setState({
  first:'',
  last:'',
  number:'',
  email:'',
  area:'',
  instagram:'',
  facebook:'',
  linkedin:'',
  twitter:''
})
event.preventDefault();
    }
}
  //logic for adding contact object to state end//

  searchFieldChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchField:event.target.value})
  }

  /*removeContacts = (event) => {
    let array = this.state.contacts; 
    let index = array.indexOf(event.target.value)
    array.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({contacts: array});
  }*/

  /*removeContacts = (id) =>{
    this.setState({
      contacts:this.state.contacts.filter((contacts,id)=> contacts.id != id)
    })
  }  */
  removeContacts = (key) => {
    const contacts = this.state.contacts; 
    contacts.splice(key,1);
    this.setState({contacts: contacts});
  }



  render() {
    const {contacts, searchField} = this.state;
    const filteredContacts =contacts.filter(contacts =>{
      return contacts.first/* this is for side bar letters [0]*/.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <NavBar         
        modalToggle={this.addModalToggle} 
        search={this.searchFieldChange}
        />
        <AddForm  
        clear={this.clearBtn}
        closeModal={this.closeModalToggle}
        showAdd={this.state.class} 
        submitData={this.submitData} 
        firstChange={this.firstChange} 
        lastChange={this.lastChange} 
        numberChange={this.numberChange}
        emailChange = {this.emailChange}
        locationChange = {this.locationChange}
        instagramChange = {this.instagramChange}
        facebookChange = {this.facebookChange}
        linkedinChange = {this.linkedinChange}
        twitterChange = {this.twitterChange}
        />
        <ContactList 
        contacts={filteredContacts} 
        removeContacts={this.removeContacts}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;



import React from 'react';
import ContactCard from './ContactCard';

const ContactList = ({contacts,removeContacts}) =>{


    return (
        <div className = 'contactDisplay' >

        {contacts.map((contact,i) =>{
            return (
                <ContactCard 
                /*key={i} 
                id={i}
                first={contacts[i].first} 
                last={contacts[i].last} 
                email={contacts[i].email} 
                number={contacts[i].number} 
                area={contacts[i].area} 
                instagram={contacts[i].instagram}
                facebook={contacts[i].facebook}
                linkedin={contacts[i].linkedin}
                twitter={contacts[i].twitter}*/
                contacts={contacts[i]}
                removeContacts={removeContacts}
                />
            );
        })
        }
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactList;

import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faInstagram } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faLinkedinIn } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faPencilAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


const ContactCard = ({removeContacts,contacts}) =>{
    const {first,last,number,email,area,instagram,facebook,linkedin,twitter} = contacts;

    return (
        <div className='contactCard'>
            <div className='cardTop'>
               <img className='contactPhoto' src= 'https://via.placeholder.com/130x130' alt='person'/> 
                <h2>{first} {last} <button className='editBtn'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} /> </button><button className='editBtn' onClick={ removeContacts }><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} /></button></h2> 
                <hr/>
            </div>
                <div className= 'cardBottom'>
                    <p>Phone Number: {number} </p>
                    <p>Email Address: {email}</p>
                    <p>Location: {area}</p>
                </div>
                <footer className='cardFooter'> 
                    <button type='button' className='instagram'><a href= {instagram} target="_blank">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} />
                    </a></button>
                    <button type='button' className='facebook'><a href= {facebook} target="_blank">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
                    </a></button>
                    <button type='button' className='linkedin'><a href= {linkedin} target="_blank">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedinIn} />
                    </a></button>
                    <button type='button' className='twitter'><a href= {twitter} target="_blank">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />
                    </a></button>
                </footer>
            </div>

    );
}

export default ContactCard;
```

Comment: why are you using `splice`? you definitely want to be using `filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are never passing the key to your function.
What is happening is the following:

```
t = [1, 2, 3]
t.splice(undefined, 1)
// now, t = [2, 3]
```

undefined is converted to 0. Thus, you always remove the first element.

Also, you are filtering your list of contacts in `App` before passing it to `ContactList` which calls the remove method. So the key available in `ContactList` does not match the index in the state list. Consider using `instagram` that should be unique.
Then, the code is updated as:

```
const ContactList = ({contacts,removeContacts}) =>{
    return (
        <div className = 'contactDisplay' >
        {contacts.map((contact,i) =>{
            return (
                <ContactCard 
                ...
                contacts={contacts[i]}
                removeContacts={() => removeContacts(contact.instagram)}
                />
            );
        })
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

and

```
removeContacts = (insta) => {
  const contacts = this.state.contacts; 
  const idx = contacts.findIndex(c => c.instagram === insta);
  if (idx >= 0) {
    contacts.splice(idx ,1);
    this.setState({contacts: contacts});
  }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should never use keys to identify objects in your array, they're used exclusively by react as a unique identifier of an object in a JSX list. You need to use a unique identifier that is in your array to find an item to delete it, so you should either introduce an `id` property to your array or use an existing unique key like email. Consider the following setup:

```
removeContacts = (email) => {
    const { contacts } = this.state;
    const newContacts = contacts.filter(item => item.email !== email);
    this.setState({ contacts: newContacts });
}

const ContactList = ({contacts,removeContacts}) =>{
    return (
        <div className = 'contactDisplay' >

        {contacts.map((contact,i) =>{
            return (
                <ContactCard 
                /*key={i} 
                id={i}
                first={contacts[i].first} 
                last={contacts[i].last} 
                email={contacts[i].email} 
                number={contacts[i].number} 
                area={contacts[i].area} 
                instagram={contacts[i].instagram}
                facebook={contacts[i].facebook}
                linkedin={contacts[i].linkedin}
                twitter={contacts[i].twitter}*/
                contacts={contacts[i]}
                removeContacts={() => removeContacts(contact.email)}
                />
            );
        })
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```